# Manipulating dirstack in bash

Tags: bash

I'm currently aliasing cd to functions as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/aliasing-cd-to-pushd-is-it-a-good-idea), however, I'd like to also exclude $HOME from the dirstack and prevent duplicates from being added to the dirstack.  Is there anyway to manipulate the dirstack without changing directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `DIRSTACK` is used to hold entries added by `pushd`. You can assign to *existing* elements of the array to modify the stack (so that the new directory is used when its turn comes with `popd`):

```
$ pushd /etc
/etc ~
$ pushd /usr
/usr /etc /~
$ echo "${DIRSTACK[@]}"
/usr /etc ~
$ DIRSTACK[1]=/var
$ echo "${DIRSTACK[@]}"
/usr /var ~
$ popd
/var
$
```

However, other attempts to add to or remove from `DIRSTACK` (aside from `pushd` and `popd`) will simply have no effect.